# Zend_Http_Client in php programming

Tags: http, zend-framework, client

Is it possible to give dynamic values to the setParameterGet or setParameterPost in Zend_Http_Client?

For example, I can give setParameterGet('fruit', 'banana'); which means that the value of the fruit is banana. However, if I want the value of the fruit to be dynamic, how should I go about doing that?

Comment: `$client->setParameterGet('fruit', $fruit)` ?

Comment: for POST parameters, you can use `$client->setParameterPost('fruit', $fruit)`. or via `setRawData`.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign your dynamic fruit name to a variable:

```
$dynamicFruit = 'banana'; //..or something else
$client->setParameterGet('fruit', $dynamicFruit);
```